# Assetic rewrite creates wrong path with "Resources/public" in it

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I added a stylesheet using assetic ...

```
{% stylesheets
    '@MyBundle/Resources/public/iCheck/all.css'
    filter='cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The all.css contains a couple of includes...

```
@import url("minimal/_all.css");
@import url("square/_all.css");
...
```

When I deliver the page, the css file is delivered as `http://localhost/app_dev.php/css/d764ee6_all_4.css` but it's paths are rewritten like this:

```
@import url("../../Resources/public/iCheck/minimal/_all.css");
@import url("../../Resources/public/iCheck/square/_all.css");
...
```

I guess the "../../Resources/public/" should not be in there. Right?
But what can I do about it?

**Directory structure**
The files are located in `MyBundle/Resources/public/`.
`/Resources/public/iCheck/all.css` includes
`/Resources/public/iCheck/minimal/_all.css`.

**My Assetic configuration:**

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    bundles:
        - MyBundle
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the cssrewrite filter, you should not use the `@...` shortcut notation. Use the path notation instead (absolute/relative path).